# mc command hangs with --version parameter when writing to stdout but works when piping to cat?

Tags: command-line, pipe, io

I observed odd behaviour of a utility binary (it's actually the minio client `mc` in a recent-ish version) when running it from the command line.

If I just run it like `./mc --version`, the command hangs forever. Even CTRL-C won't let me out.

If I run it like `./mc --version | cat` or  `./mc  --version | less`, I can get the output to display just fine.

When running  `strace ./mc --version` I can see the output of `strace` stops at `write(1, "...")`.

What could be the issue of this behaviour? How could I debug this further?

I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with `mc` itself but something with the env where we run the binary.

To make it even more weird, I'm pretty sure this worked a few weeks/months back without some piping through `cat` or the likes.

Comment: In both cases, `mc` writes to its stdout, in `./mc --version | cat`, stdout is a pipe, but that is stdout in `./mc --version`? Do you run that from a terminal? Then is it a terminal device?

Comment: What's the system, what version of `mc`, can you show the last few lines of the output of `strace`?

Comment: I do not know the command `mc` but I assume 1) `--version` is not a valid parameter to show the version and exit, 2) the command enters a keyboard-interactive session and therefore "hangs", 3) detects when output is to a pipe and behaves differently (many commands do).